# Ответ сервера содержит Authorization header, но его не видно в Vue приложении

Tags: vue.js, spring-boot, heroku

У меня есть Vue приложение работающее вместе с REST сервисом (Spring Boot). Авторизация реализована с помощью Spring Security.

Cross origin запросы разрешены:

- раз: https://github.com/pazukdev/bearings-info-api/blob/bd25b1462df31221c2cf7cfc01a60e3245a9b3da/backend/src/main/java/com/pazukdev/backend/config/SpringSecurityConfig.java#L30
- два: https://github.com/pazukdev/bearings-info-api/blob/bd25b1462df31221c2cf7cfc01a60e3245a9b3da/backend/src/main/java/com/pazukdev/backend/config/Config.java#L47

Все хедеры разрешены: https://github.com/pazukdev/bearings-info-api/blob/bd25b1462df31221c2cf7cfc01a60e3245a9b3da/backend/src/main/java/com/pazukdev/backend/config/Config.java#L48

В моем Vue приложении я получаю authorization таким образом:

```
let credentialsUrl = "username=" + this.username + "&" + "password=" + this.password;
axios 
    .post('https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/login', credentialsUrl) 
    .then(response => { 
        if (response.status === 200) { 
            let authorization = response.headers.authorization; 
            this.$store.dispatch("setAuthorization", authorization); 
        } 
     );
}
```

На локалхосте все работает: я получаю Bearer токен из хедера.

Сейчас REST сервис задеплоен на удаленный сервер (Heroku). Консоль в Chrome показывает, что хедер Authorization в ответе сервера есть. Но в Vue я его уже нет. Итог: authorization undefined.

В чем может быть причина?

**Дополнение 1:**

Вывод console.log(JSON.stringify(response)):

*Ответ с localhost, authorization присутствует:*

{"data":"","status":200,"statusText":"","headers":{"pragma":"no-cache","date":"Fri, 25 Oct 2019 09:17:06 GMT","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","server":"nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)","authorization":"Bearer eyJ0b2tlblR5cGUiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzZWN1cmUtYXBpIiwiYXVkIjoic2VjdXJlLWFwcCIsInN1YiI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTcyODU5MDI2LCJyb2xlcyI6WyJST0xFX0FETUlOIl19.1SBIxIIk0qkja05_6t3lmPIpBh58LajaMvdW-i9xkzqVZNSspJ-zQ9E07xVxut02QaxUx9oHeeap76mqL1PUhA","x-frame-options":"DENY","access-control-allow-origin":"*","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"0","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","expires":"0"},"config":{"url":"/backend/login","method":"post","data":"username=admin&password=admin","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1},"request":{}}

*Ответ с удаленного сервера, authorization отсутствует:*

{"data":"","status":200,"statusText":"","headers":{"pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","expires":"0"},"config":{"url":"https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/login","method":"post","data":"username=admin&password=admin","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1},"request":{}}

*Ответ с сервера (и с локалхоста, и с удаленного - одинаково) в консоли Chrome (Network, Headers), Authorization присутствеует:*

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0b2tlblR5cGUiOiJKV1Qi...

**Дополнение 2:**

Между конфигурацииями c REST сервисом на локалхосте и на удаленном сервере у меня есть различие: на локалхосте между клиентом Vue и Spring-Boot есть обратный прокси сервер (nginx). Между клиентом и удаленным сервером он отсутствует. М.б. в этом причина?

Comment: а если так `response.headers.Authorization`?

Comment: @Дмытрык так то же самое. В Vue в объекте response просто нет authorization. Добавил вывод логов ответов к вопросу. И второе дополнение про nginx. Мне кажется, что уши ростут оттуда (из его отсутствия между удаленными серверами)

Comment: так все таки, ответ приходит без этого заголовка?

Comment: @Дмытрык Сам ответ сервера, судя по консоли браузера (+ в Postman тоже пробовал), хедер Authorization содержит ("Удаленный сервер, консоль Chrome, Authorization присутствеует: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0b2tlblR5cGUiOiJKV1Qi...") одинаково в обоих случаях: и на локалхосте и на удаленном сервере. Но в том response, который в коде Vue приложения при работе на локалхосте authorization есть, а на удаленном сервере - нет.

Comment: @Дмытрык , т.е., раз хедер присутствует в ответе сервера, но его нет на фронте, то, по логике, данный хедер не разрешен для моего фронта и проблема на стороне сервера (?). Но у меня в конфиге разрешены все хедеры: https://github.com/pazukdev/bearings-info-api/blob/bd25b1462df31221c2cf7cfc01a60e3245a9b3da/backend/src/main/java/com/pazukdev/backend/config/Config.java#L48

Comment: Authorization - это заголовок для запроса, в ответе он не должен присутствовать совсем. Опишите, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Из этого заголовка я на фронте беру токен, который сохраняю и передаю во всех запросах к серверу (до момента, когда будет совершен логаут): 
Тут сохраняю: https://github.com/pazukdev/vue-page-test/blob/cb1c1185a1108d74a93aedb3d24ab0c25271bcfe/src/components/Login.vue#L105
Пример использования: https://github.com/pazukdev/vue-page-test/blob/cb1c1185a1108d74a93aedb3d24ab0c25271bcfe/src/components/Item.vue#L841

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Должно помочь добавление сервером в ответ заголовка:
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization`